# Hash table implementation for storing strings

Tags: c, hashtable

This is my code for a hash table which stores string values.To use Linear probing in my "insert" function, I need to check whether the pointer is NULL at that specific hash value. I Haven't completed my insert function yet, but I am stuck because when I check for **if(the_hash_table[n]==NULL)**   inside the insert function, it does not enter the branch. Before hashing the value if I print "the_hash_table[1]" it prints "faz", but after that step when I print it, it prints some weird characters. Where have I gone wrong?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    /*
    creates a hash table of size 10
    */

    char** create_hash_table(){



        char* the_hash_table[10];   // defines a hash table to store strings

        *the_hash_table=malloc(sizeof(char*)*10); // allocates memory in the heap for the hash table
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){ // this loop initializes the string pointers to NULL at the starting point of the hash table
            the_hash_table[i]=NULL;
        }
        return &the_hash_table; // returns the address of the hash table to the main memory

    }

    /*
    this is a method to insert a string into the relevant position of the hash table
    */

    void insert(char* the_string,char** the_hash_table){

        printf("%s",the_hash_table[1]);
        int n=hash(the_string);
        printf("%s",the_hash_table[1]);
        if(the_hash_table[n] == NULL)
            the_hash_table[n]=the_string;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't allocated memory correctly.

You define an automatic variable, `the_hash_table` as an array of pointers. You allocate some memory and put the pointer to that memory in your array. You immediately overwrite that pointer (and the other elements of `the_hash_table`) with null pointers.

Then you return a pointer to the local array, but the array no longer exists once the function exits. It is *always* wrong to return a pointer to an automatic variable from the function it's defined in.

What you should do is:

```
char** create_hash_table(void) {
    char** the_hash_table = malloc(sizeof(*the_hash_table) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        the_hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
    return the_hash_table;
}
```

So, `the_hash_table` is a local variable that points to the allocated memory. You return its value, which is the address of the allocated memory. Then in `main` you would `free(the_hash_table)` not `free(*the_hash_table)`.

Also, in your `hash` function there is no point copying the string: just read the characters from `the_string[i]`. Even if there was a point in copying it, the buffer that you create in order to do so is 1 byte too small, it needs to be `strlen(the_string)+1` because the length returned by `strlen` does not include the 0 byte that terminates the string.

Comment: This was really helpful. Now I know where I went wrong. Thank you. :)